# Bad page break with \newenvironment, \refstepcounter and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, page-breaking, environments, counters

I tried to define some environment but came across bad page breaks sometimes. The minimal working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} % page break is correct when removing this line

\newcounter{question}
\newenvironment{question}{\par\refstepcounter{question}\thequestion. }{}
% page break is correct when changing \refstepcounter to \stepcounter

\begin{document}

\fontsize{40pt}{50pt}\selectfont

\begin{question}111\end{question}
\begin{question}111\end{question}
\begin{question}111\end{question}

\begin{question}
If ... Then ... ( ).\par
(A) 11; (B) 22; (C) 33; (D) 44.
\end{question}

\begin{question}111\end{question}
\begin{question}111\end{question}
\begin{question}111\end{question}
\begin{question}111\end{question}
\begin{question}111\end{question}

\end{document}
```

The page break is correct when removing hyperref package, or changing \refstepcounter to \stepcounter. What is the problem with this example?

Comment: Thanks for posting a very clear MWE. I can reproduce the problem behavior. Fortunately, it disappears if one loads the `geometry` package as well.

Comment: @Mico geometry doesn't fix the issue it just changes the size a bit so makes the tipping point happen at a different place so makes the issue go from this example.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Avoid putting specials in vmode

```
\newenvironment{question}{\par\mbox{}\refstepcounter{question}\thequestion. }{}
```