# Additional space by \refstepcounter

Tags: spacing, hyperref

Maybe this is related to
[Bad page break with \newenvironment, \refstepcounter and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136227/bad-page-break-with-newenvironment-refstepcounter-and-hyperref?rq=1),
but the answer there (`insert \mbox{}`) didn't help.

In the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{number}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\[a\]
\refstepcounter{number}
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

the line `\refstepcounter{number}` produces additional vertical space, which is not there, if I use `\stepcounter{number}` oder erase the `hyperref` Package. How can I avoid this space?

Comment: Why do you want to do the \refstepcounter exactly there?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The \refstepcounter is executed dozens of times via several nested macros. Just a few times it is "exactly there" (after the \[...\]). You mean it would be easiest to reorganize the macros such that \refstepcounter can never come directly after \[...\]?

Comment: Yes, it would be better if it is only executed in a place where the whatsits for the link anchor doesn't harm. Or if you disable anchors there.

Comment: Hm, I can't see how to reorganize it. The \refstepcounter is placed in something like \newenvironment{display}{}{\refstepcounter{number}}. It would not work at the beginning of the environment and I also cannot prevent the content of the (proof-like) environment from ending with a \[\].
How could I 'disable anchors'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the original \refstepcounter. It won't insert a space, but also no anchor, so links will probably go to the wrong places:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{number}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item xxxxxxxxxxxxx 
\[aaaaaaaaaaa\]
\refstepcounter{number}
\item xxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item xxxxxxxxxxxxx 
\[aaaaaaaaaaaa\]
\csname H@refstepcounter\endcsname{number}
\item xxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it would be even better to save the original '\refstepcounter' via '\let\rsc\refstepcounter' before calling 'hyperref'. Then replace '\csname H@refstepcounter\endcsname{number}' by '\rsc{number}'.